# Font loading issue in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, fonts, visual-studio-2019

I've recently installed the [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) font for Visual Studio 2019, version 16.6.3

The issue that I have is that after I shut down my computer, the font won't load properly unless I close VS and re-install it (and, when I do that, Windows also tells me that the font is already installed and I have to confirm that I want to overwrite it) in order to get it to load properly.

The confusing thing about this issue is that even when the font doesn't load correctly (it loads the default font instead) it stil appears to be properly selected in Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts And Colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by installing the font for all the users, which can be achieved by simply left clicking the .ttf file and selecting the "Install for all users" option.